# C++/CLI namespace does not exist error

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a problem with my code writed in C++/CLI. I have an *'WidowsFormApplication': a namespace with this name does not exist* error in file Database.h. I tried almost everything, and searched in web for an answer, but i can't. What is wrong with my code? Code is down below. Thanks.

***short review of "form1.h":***

```
#ifndef Form1_h
#define Form1_h

#include"Database.h"



namespace WindowsFormApplication{


using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^
```

***"database.h":***

```
#ifndef Database_h
#define Database_h

#include"Form1.h"

namespace Database{


using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace WindowsFormApplication;//error

public ref class Column{
private: List<System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^> ^columnName;
private: int numberOfColumn;
private: int x;
private: int tabIndex;
private: int width;
private: Form1^ mainFrame;//also error becouse of namespace
public: Column(Form1^ mainFrame);//and error
public: void push_back();
public: void click();
};
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including "Form1.h" in "Database.h" and "Database.h" in "Form1.h". Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Actually i think i don't need, when i delete #include "database.h" line from form1.h file project is compiling now. I will create an database object in main file. I learn that i cannot do this include in both files. Thanks i thought #ifndef definition protects me from any errors from this side :)